# AngularJs: When view content fully loaded execute a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I call a function when view is fully loaded (text, images and everything)?

I've tried the following in my main controller, but it's alerting before content loads.

```
$(window).load(function() {
 alert('dsdsds');
});
```

I'm using `ui-router`, so I tried this as well in my main controller,

```
$scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function($currentRoute, $previousRoute) {
    alert('sasas');
});
```

Here too, it's alerting before any content loads.

How can I do this?

Comment: have you defered you javascript in your `html` or put it at the bottom? that should make all of the DOM load before your JS

Comment: exact which content should be loaded to fire the event you wanted?

Comment: @JoeLloyd: It's in the bottom of the main index.html

Comment: @PankajParkar: I want to alert something once my current view content is fully loaded.

Comment: @Body do you wanted to wait until `ng-repeat` load? or is there any specific component should be loaded before showing alert?

Comment: @PankajParkar: There is no any specific content. I want the alert after everything is loaded when I clicked a state. I'm using the same in jQuery as $(window).load(function(){ .... }). I don't know how to do the same in Angular.

Comment: @Body could you try the `$timeout(function(){  alert('Loaded'; )})` inside your controller

Comment: @PankajParkar: I think $timeout wouldn't give me any accurate result as content loading is also based on the network and other things such as cdn  delays. Also each view has it's own amount of data thus can't predict the exact timeout delay.

Comment: @Body oh cool got the point..you need to show the after all the ajax gets response correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$viewContentLoaded` .It is emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
     /...
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've try this, but it's alerting before content loaded. I want the alert after my view content is fully loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want to watch the stateChangeSuccess DOM object to change and then do something.

```
 $scope.$watch('$stateChangeSuccess', function($currentRoute, $previousRoute){
    // do something
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've tried this, but it's alerting before content loaded. I want the alert after my view content is fully loaded.